# About constructor overload of a class template

Tags: c++

now I am just really new to C++, currently I have a piece of code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Test1
{
    public:
    Test1():var1(1) {
        cout << "Constructor1" << endl;
    }

    Test1(T a):var1(a) {
        cout << "Constructor2" << endl;
    }

    private:
    int var1;
};

template<typename T>
class Test2
{
    public:
    Test2():var2(x) {
        cout << "Constructor3" << endl;
    };

    private:
    int x;
    Test1<int> var2;
};

int main() 
{
    Test2<int> var3;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will just be

```
Constructor2
Constructor3
```

I wonder why the constructor2 will be called instead of constructor1, since in the class Test2, when creating the object var2, I didn't pass in any parameters, shouldn't the constructor without parameter being called?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean you "didn't pass in any parameters"?  The `x` part of `var2(x)` is the parameter you're passing to the constructor, to construct your `var2`. Sure, this is undefined behavior, but for other reasons.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi, oh I didn't know that, I thought that var2(x) is a initialize list which is equal to var2 = x?

Comment: No, that's a constructor invocation. Everything in the initializer list is a constructor invocation. That's what an initializer list is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Aha, now I get it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for a variable is determined by its initialization.  You have an initialization list on your Test2 constructor

```
 Test2():var2(x) {
```

so you have to look there for how Test2::var2 is initialized.  In the initialization list, you're passing the integer `x` (that's not initialized to anything), so it calls the Test1 constructor that takes an integer.

If you don't explicitly initialize var2 in your initializer list (for example, if you just assign to it in the constructor body), then it will be default initialized and say "constructor 1" instead of 2

Comment: Oh thank you so much, now i kinda get the idea!